# Install Ubuntu 12.04 on reduced portion of D: drive

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, system-installation

I have Windows 7 on my `C:` drive and my `D:` drive has 155GB of space.  I want to install Ubuntu on the `D:` drive, but **I only want to allow 25-30GB of space from the `D:` drive for Ubuntu**.

How should I make the partition on the `D:` drive?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the Disk Management tool with administrative rights, and once it opens you can shrink D drive to the amount that you want to give Ubuntu.
[image]

[image]

Once done that space would be labeled as Unallocated, and you can use it during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Is your D:/ drive empty or it contains some important data ...!

if not then  **you can directly boot up liveCD or bootable Pendrive with UBUNTU can use it's partitioning tool** 

else **use window disk management tool, it's GUI you can do like** *MITCH* has shown to you ..!